# AddAction on a Notification to execute a Method in Xamarin ( PCL)

Tags: android, xamarin, notifications, xamarin.forms

I want to make an execution with the Help of a Method in PCL `AddData();`, but am looking for a way to attach it on the property of a notification called `AddAction` below:

```
.AddAction(Resource.Drawable.tick_notify, "Take", pIntent)
```

but i don't know how to wire it out because the **Third** parameter needs a `PendingIntent` ,**Is there a way of adding the AddData Method from the `PCL`?
to perform a certain action?**

**EDITED**

**Service.cs**

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;

namespace Diabetes.Droid
{
    [Service]
    public class Mservice : Service
    {
        //Receiver class
        private AlarmReceiver mReceiver = new AlarmReceiver();
        /// <summary>
        /// Raises the bind event.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="intent">Intent.</param>
        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            return null;
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Called by the system when the service is first created.
        /// </summary>
        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();
            //IntentnFilter all actities to receive information
            IntentFilter iF = new IntentFilter();
            iF.AddAction("com.android.music.metachanged");
            iF.AddAction("com.android.music.playstatechanged");
            iF.AddAction("com.android.music.playbackcomplete");
            iF.AddAction("com.android.music.queuechanged");
            iF.AddAction("com.htc.music.metachanged");
            iF.AddAction("fm.last.android.metachanged");
            iF.AddAction("com.sec.android.app.music.metachanged");
            iF.AddAction("com.nullsoft.winamp.metachanged");
            iF.AddAction("com.amazon.mp3.metachanged");
            iF.AddAction("com.miui.player.metachanged");
            iF.AddAction("com.real.IMP.metachanged");
            iF.AddAction("com.sonyericsson.music.metachanged");
            iF.AddAction("com.rdio.android.metachanged");
            iF.AddAction("com.samsung.sec.android.MusicPlayer.metachanged");
            iF.AddAction("com.andrew.apollo.metachanged");
            //register receiver with intentnfilter
            RegisterReceiver(mReceiver, iF);
        }
        public override void OnDestroy()
        {
            base.OnDestroy();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No there is no to way to link directly method to Notification action.

Certainly because notification are runned on system phone interface, out of your app code.

You should build a pending intent and use a receiver to be able to receive the callback.

This restriction exists in the same way in Xamarin.

You can find an exemple (in standard Android java code) in google sample [UniversalMusicPlayer#MediaNotificationManager.java](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer/blob/67a35ffefff9cd1c04089284492caa73dde8cae3/mobile/src/main/java/com/example/android/uamp/MediaNotificationManager.java)

Create your intent :

```
mAddDataPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mService, REQUEST_CODE,
                new Intent(ACTION_ADD_DATA).setPackage(pkg), PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

Then when building your notification :

```
notificationBuilder.addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(icon, label, mAddDataPendingIntent));
```

Register your broadcast :

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
                filter.addAction(ACTION_ADD_DATA);
                mService.registerReceiver(this, filter);
```

And receive action :

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final String action = intent.getAction();
    LogHelper.d(TAG, "Received intent with action " + action);
    switch (action) {
        case ACTION_ADD_DATA:
            addData();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: According to your code i can replace   `mTransportControls.play();`  with `AddData();` Method.

Comment: The other problem am facing is Java , if at all you provided C# code

Comment: Yes this is where to call your method. I've updated my answer to be more related to your context. About C# version, sorry but my knowledges about xamarin are too weak to provide you a complete example.

Comment: Oooh gosh am dead

Comment: try to follow this thread https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/84134/how-to-add-buttons-to-push-notification

Comment: i followed that thread even i commented on it , but i see your answer more closer but the problem is java conversion to C#